# qsub: Specifying non-consecutive datasets with the -t option

Tags: linux, unix, sungridengine, qsub

I'm submitting jobs to a Sun Grid Engine using the `qsub` command.  The `-t` option to `qsub` enables me to specify the datasets upon which I want to call my script -- e.g.,

```
$ qsub . . . -t 101-103 my_script.sh
```

My question is, is it possible to specify non-consecutive datasets with the `-t` option?  For example, say I wanted to run the script on `101` and `103`, but not `102`.  How would I accomplish that?

And, more generally, how would I select arbitrarily numbered datasets?

I would like an answer that works in practice for a large number of datasets -- far beyond the two used in this toy example.

Comment: did you try multiple `-t` opts? i.e. `-t 101 -t 103`? (not a qsub user, just applying a quasi-std cmd-line processing trick;-) ) Good luck.

Comment: @shellter ah, that's a good idea for the toy example i posted, but in reality i have to specify fifty datasets, none of which are consecutive, so one `-t` for each would require a lot of typing.

Comment: Something like `qsub $( for i in 100 103 ; do printf -- "-t %s " $i ; done) --other_qsub_opts ....`, and of course you can replace `100 103` with `$(< jobList.txt)`. Just guessing ;-) Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to run regularly spaced datasets -- e.g., `1, 3, 5, . . .` or `10, 15, 20, . . .` -- then @chrk's answer is the one to use.

For arbitrarily numbered datasets, using `-t` is not possible.  The same functionality can be attained, however, using the `submit` command (with the `-f` option) instead of `qsub`.

```
$ submit . . . -s my_script.sh -f my_datasets.txt
```

The file `my_datasets.txt` contains one dataset per line, as in

```
101
103
```

I'm not sure how specific this solution is to the particular configuration of my computing environment.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about that, but quoting from [`qsub`'s man page](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qsub.html), on paragraph where `-t` is explained:

> . . .
>
> The task id range specified in the option argument  may be a single
>   number, a simple range of the form n-m or a range with a step size.
>   Hence, the task id range specified  by  2-10:2 would result in the
>   task id indexes 2, 4, 6, 8, and 10, for a total of 5 identical tasks,
>
> . . .

So, maybe:

```
$ qsub . . . -t 101-103:2 my_script.sh
```

would do.

Comment: aha, that's perfect for me, because what i need is `1, 3, 5, . . . 99`.